# Rails: change default sender in action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I am sending email using action mailer in my rails app. But it allows only one default sender. This is my UserMailer class:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default :from => "example@example.com"
 def welcome_email(user, order)
  @user = user
  @order = order
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Your Order")
 end
 def signup_email(user)
  @user = user
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Thank you.")
 end
 def invite_confirm(curuser,usemail,post)
  @greeting = "Hi"
  @user = curuser
  @post = post
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Hello")
 end
end
```

I tried this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 def welcome_email(user, order)
@user = user
    @order = order
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Your Order", :from => "abc@xyz.com")
 end
 def signup_email(user)
   @user = user
   mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Thank you.", :from => "qwe@asd.com")
 end
 def invite_confirm(curuser,usemail,post)
  @greeting = "Hi"
  @user = curuser
  @post = post
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Hello", :from => "zyx@asd.com")
 end
end
```

But still it is sending email from "example@example.com"

Is there any way to change sender for each method written in UserMailer class? Am i supposed to change anywhere else?

In config/environments/development.rb and config/environments/production.rb i have this:

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => "587",
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :authentication => "plain",
  :user_name => "example@example.com",
  :password => "example",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true 
 }
```

I guess, i should not change anything here.

Answer (score 8):

You can pass it as a parameter to the `mail` method:

```
def new_mail
  mail from: "example@example.com", to: "user@example.com"
end
```

Comment: Hey, i wanna send email from various users. I updated my question. Can u help on it?

Comment: You need to send several emails then :)

Answer (score 2):

I found that, this can't be done using smtp. Need to use amazon SES which allows multi sender support.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to send mail with three different emails of the for-each action. Because you use gmail, you need [Sending mail from a different address](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en&ctx=mail).

> No single vendor is optimal for all three types of email; you likely
>   will use several vendors.
>
> For “company email,” that is, sending individual email to customers or
>   business associates, you’ll probably use Gmail or [Google Apps for
>   Business](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/index.html). For a single address, you can set up a single Gmail account
>   to receive and [send email from a different address](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=22370). More likely,
>   you’ll want several email addresses for your company mail. For that,
>   use Google Apps for Business.

[Send Email with Rails](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-send-email.html)

Answer (score -1):

Here's what i use, it allows to make a "title" different.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      default :from => '"example" <example@domain.com>'

      def send_signup_email(user)
        @user = user
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'example')
      end
    end
```